# Компонент не рендерится после изменения в data

Tags: vue.js

Хочу сделать небольшой справочник, в котором можно будет добавлять, удалять компании. Столкнулся с такой проблемой, почему при изменении `data` в строке

```
this.companies[key] = {};
```

не происходит перерисовка компонента, но при этом в консоли уже можно увидеть, что объект удален.

Сам код:

```
<template>
    <div>
        <tr v-for="company in companies" :key="company.INN">
            <td v-for="property in company" :key="property">
                {{ property }}
            </td>
            <td>
                <button v-on:click="removeCompany(company.name)">Remove company</button>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
    export default {
        name: '',
        props: [],
        methods: {
            removeCompany(removdCompany) {
                for (let key in this.companies) {
                    if (this.companies[key].name === removdCompany) {   
                        this.companies[key] = {};
                    }
                }
            }
        },
        data() {
            return {
                companies: [
                    { 
                        name: 'Cola',
                        CEO: 'Иванов',
                        INN: '2'
                    },
                    { 
                        name: 'PepsiCo',
                        CEO: 'Петров',
                        INN: '3'
                    }
                ]
            }
        }
    };
</script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Чтоб работало вам нужно использовать методы, которые будут мутировать имеющееся `data` и `props`. Такие, как `.push(), .pop(), .splice()`. если переопределить объект, работать так не будет. `Vue.js` основан на гетторах и сетторах.

> Почитайте про *мутабельность/иммутабельность* и про *геттеры/сеттеры*
>   в javascript чтоб у вас было понимание как оно устроино

### Код

Посмотрите я оставил комментарии на изменения

```
<template>
  <div>
    <!-- Добавляем индекс -->
    <tr v-for="(company, index) in companies" :key="company.INN">
      <td v-for="property in company" :key="property">
        {{ property }}
      </td>
      <td>
        <!-- Передаем индекс в метод вместо имени -->
        <button @click="removeCompany(index)" type="button">
          Remove company
        </button>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  methods: {
    // Вырезаем из массива один елемен по индексу методом .splice();
    removeCompany(index) {
      this.companies.splice(index, 1);
    }
  },
  data() {
    return {
      companies: [
        { 
          name: 'Cola',
          CEO: 'Иванов',
          INN: '2'
        },
        { 
          name: 'PepsiCo',
          CEO: 'Петров',
          INN: '3'
        }
      ]
    }
  }
};
</script>
```